# Multiple row update with sum operation in SQL trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have 3 tables. I want to add a sum of data in tables to another with update.

```sql
   CREATE TRIGGER [active_plan_increase_total]
   ON [dbo].[wallet_plan]
   after UPDATE
   AS
   BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON
       declare @id int, @user_id  int, @inc_id int, @inc_rate float, @status nvarchar(50), @current_balance float
       
       select @user_id = inserted.user_id, @inc_id = inserted.rate_id, @status= inserted.status from inserted
       
       select @inc_rate = sum( Increase_Rate.inc_rate ), @user_id =wallet_plan.user_id from Increase_Rate join inserted i on  Increase_Rate.Id = i.rate_id inner join wallet_plan on wallet_plan.user_id = i.user_id where wallet_plan.user_id = i.user_id group by wallet_plan.user_id 

       select @current_balance = User_Total.current_btc from User_Total where User_Total.user_id = @user_id    
       
       update User_Total set User_Total.current_btc = (User_Total.current_btc + Increase_Rate.inc_rate)  from User_Total join inserted i on User_Total.user_id = i.user_id 
       inner join Increase_Rate on Increase_Rate.Id = i.rate_id 

   END
```

This code works fine but I want to use sum for increase rate. Because sometimes an id has multiple inc_rates. How can I combine these two queries for multiple rows.

I have a table named Increase Rate. This increase rate id related rate_id and I want to get sum of inc_rate of a user_id related. I want to add these results of to user_total's current balance data. There are multiple rows in increase rate and multiple rows in user total. How can I write a trigger that connect that table.

```sql
    CREATE TRIGGER [active_plan_increase_total]
    ON [dbo].[wallet_plan]
    after UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        declare @id int, @user_id  int, @inc_id int, @inc_rate float, @status nvarchar(50), @current_balance float
        
        select @user_id = inserted.user_id, @inc_id = inserted.rate_id, @status= inserted.status from inserted      
        
        select @inc_rate = sum( Increase_Rate.inc_rate ), @user_id =wallet_plan.user_id from Increase_Rate join inserted i on  Increase_Rate.Id = i.rate_id inner join wallet_plan on wallet_plan.user_id = i.user_id where wallet_plan.user_id = i.user_id group by wallet_plan.user_id 

        select @current_balance = User_Total.current_btc from User_Total where User_Total.user_id = @user_id    
                
        update User_Total set User_Total.current_btc =( User_Total.current_btc +  @inc_rate)   from  User_Total  join inserted i on User_Total.user_id = i.user_id  
        inner join Increase_Rate on Increase_Rate.Id = i.rate_id where User_Total.user_id = i.user_id

    END
```

This is adding last inc_rate to all users. This has to be adding sum of increase rates for each users are differently.

Comment: You've made a classic trigger 101 mistake, by assuming that `inserted` will only contain one row. It can contain any number of rows and your code needs to handle that.

Comment: @DaleK every row affected but only one rate. I want to use and update for each user's sum of rates. and sometimes, rates are more then one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per DaleK the trigger should either allow for multiple row inserts or it could raiserror or throw.  Also, triggers execute whether or not there are any rows in the 'inserted' psuedo-table so it's good to make sure nothing executes if nothing is inserted (if that's appropriate).  My refactoring came up with this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [active_plan_increase_total]
ON [dbo].[wallet_plan]
after UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
if exists (select * from inserted)
        with rate_incr_cte([user_id], incr_rate) as (
            select i.[user_id], sum(ir.inc_rate)
            from Increase_Rate ir 
                 join inserted i on  ir.Id = i.rate_id 
            group by i.[user_id]) 
        update ut 
        set current_btc =( User_Total.current_btc+ic.incr_rate)
        from User_Total ut
             join rate_incr_cte ic on ut.[user_id] = ic.[user_id];
END
```

Comment: Hi @SteveC, I am still trying but script is updating and i can't see any error but trigger is not accepting these codes. I am not good at in these kind of trigger querries. Can you help me to solve this^^ 
And also inc-rate don't have  user_id. wallet_plan and user_total has user_id. Maybe the error comes from this line ```with curr_tot_cte([user_id], sum_inc_rate) as (``` but i am not sure

Comment: the [user_id] in the select list needed to be aliased.  That would've thrown an error.  I updated

Comment: yeah now it works great. but it multiplies the sum of inc-rate with count of user_id even there is group by. I have the same issue in this code
```select @inc_rate =  sum( Increase_Rate.inc_rate ) from Increase_Rate join inserted i on  Increase_Rate.Id = i.rate_id inner join wallet_plan on wallet_plan.user_id = i.user_id where wallet_plan.user_id = i.user_id group by wallet_plan.user_id 

```

Comment: the issue is still going on. I try dividing to the count of user_id but that gives me half of the result.

Comment: I removed the join to wallet_plan in the cte as it shouldn't be needed.  Perhaps that was the issue.

Comment: thanks so much =) now it is working. How can i learn these kind of trigger. Is there a name for it?